# java client application session resumption

Tags: java, ssl, java-client

I am making a number of calls from a java client application to a server using a TLS connection.  To avoid the TLS handshake overhead, I would like to resume the session using a session ID, similar to what a web browser does.  I am currently establishing each request using an HttpsURLConenction object.

How is this accomplished in Java?  What API am I looking for?

Comment: Can any existing software do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I used Apache's HttpClient API rather than the HttpsURLConnection.  I am now able to keep the SSL context and make multiple calls without the need to do the full handshake (e.g. client signing operation).

`SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sslcontext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(),null);
sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1.2" }, null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
...
//called multiple times
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();`

Comment: This was a long time ago, but if I remember correctly, I was solving a problem where the client needed to do multiple signing operations.  I don't remember the specifics, but it did resolve a problem where signing operations were required every time a call was made.

Answer (score 0):

Java already supports session resumption *in toto*. You don't have to do anything at either end.